# Python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I am using docxtpl and format function to generate a several of word documents but I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Final report Card\Final Report Card.py", line 68, in <module>
tpl.save("./final Report Cards/{}_Final Report Cards.docx".format(file_name))
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docxtpl\__init__.py", line 632, in save self.docx.save(filename, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 135, in save self._part.save(path_or_stream)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 111, in save self.package.save(path_or_stream)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 172, in save PackageWriter.write(pkg_file, self.rels, self.parts)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgwriter.py", line 32, in write phys_writer = PhysPkgWriter(pkg_file)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 141, in __init__self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED)
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1239, in __init__self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './final Report Cards/Tester_111111_A1B _Final Report Cards.docx'
```

The code is:

```
os.mkdir("./Final Report Cards_{}".format(context["cohort"]))
  for context in contexts:
  tpl = DocxTemplate("Final report card  template for Pathway.docx")
  tpl.render(context)
  file_name = str(context["name"]) + "_" + str(context["student_number"]) + "_" + str(context["cohort"])
  tpl.save("./final Report Cards/{}_Final Report Cards.docx".format(file_name))
```

Thank you!

Comment: it seems to be the `.` dot? are you trying to back to a directory? probably it's `"../final Report Cards/{}_Final Report Cards.docx"`  or else kindly check your file.